# I can't use my User model in my view

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to peform a method such as  `getUsername()` in a foreach of posts but it gives me this error:

```
Class 'User' not found (View: /home/stackingcoder/development/PHP/internetstuffer/resources/views/index.blade.php)
```

I already have this in my HomeController.php: `use App\User;` but it still doesn't work. Does someone know why?

Here is the code of my view:

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-message"></i>{{ $post->getTitle() }} | {{ User::find( $post->getUser_id() )->getUsername() }} </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {{ $post->getText() }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Did you try Fully qualified name? (\App\User::find( $post->getUser_id() )->getUsername())

Comment: I know this doesn't andwer your question (it's already answered) but maybe it's better if you do something like $post->createdBy()->getUsername() using hasMany relationships? It'll make your code much cleaner and easier to use

Comment: @JoseGarrido I already using hasMany relations. Can you tell me ecactly how to fix it in your way?

Answer (score 0):

@pilec says:

> Did you try Fully qualified name? (\App\User::find( $post->getUser_id() )->getUsername())

And it worked! Thanks for the answer, now i know how to do it as well with other models and classes!